# Minimum edge-disjoint path cover of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given an undirected connected graph, $G$, I know that the minimum number of edge-disjoint paths needed to cover every edge is given by half the number of odd-degree vertices.

However, I have absolutely no idea how to prove this. I was wondering if anyone could sketch a proof or point me in the direction of one. I've seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2028594/minimum-number-of-edge-disjoint-paths-needed-to-cover-a-graph) already and can't really follow the logic.

Comment: Which parts of Henning's proof do you get and which parts are confusing?

Comment: @TrevorGunn In particular, I don't see how it is clear that at least that many paths will be needed, nor do I see why you must have reached an odd degree vertex when you have no where else to go.

I should point out that I'm not a mathematician, I'm a physicist, so if it's a bunch of trivial stuff I'm missing I'm happy to take pointers towards a textbook. I have the Bollobas one and the Trudeau one with me and neither were particularly enlightening.

Comment: If you've reached a vertex and have nowhere else to go, and if it's not the vertex you started from, then you must have arrived at that vertex one more time than you left it: $x$ departures, $x+1$ arrivals, using a different edge each time, so $2x+1$ edges used, no more edges left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can think of adding a path to cover the edges of $G$ as removing a set of edges from $G$ along that path. At each step, the degree of the vertices in the interior of the path decrease by $2$ and the vertices at the ends have their degree decreased by $1$. The goal is to have every vertex have degree $0$ (which you will note, is even).

So we need every vertex to have an even degree at the end. We also note, that the number of vertices of odd degree decreases by at most $2$ because vertices can only go from odd to even if they are endpoints of the path. Therefore we need as many paths as half the number of odd vertices assuming we are losing two odd vertices at each step.

Then, as bof points out in the comments, if you enter a vertex with degree $2d$ then there are $2d - 1$ edges left to leave from and odd numbers are always positive, so we can always leave.

Comment: Is that construction optimal?  Will it always make the least number of paths?

Comment: @Eyal This is one step in Henning's construction in the linked question. As he says "clearly at least that many paths will be needed, and it's not too difficult to see that you can construct a covering at set of exactly that many paths greedily." Here "that many" refers to half the number of odd-degree vertices.